# Pagination Shows same results

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using codeigniter 3 I have setup pagination. When I click on the next link I get the same results minus the first post, I cannot seem to find what is causing this.

I tried removing the offset and not allowing numbers, and I still have no change.

controller

```
public function index($offset = 0){

//Pagination
   $config['base_url'] = base_url().'posts/index/';
   $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('posts');
   $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
   $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
   $config['per_page'] = 5;
   $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
   $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
   $config['display_pages'] = FALSE;



   $this->pagination->initialize($config);

  $data['links']  = $this->pagination->create_links();


  $data['title'] = 'Newest';

  $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_posts(FALSE,$config['per_page'],$offset);


  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

model

```
public function get_posts($slug = FALSE, $limit=FALSE,$offset = FALSE){


if($limit){
  $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);
}


if($slug === FALSE){
  $this->db->order_by('created_time','DESC');
  $this->db->join('categories','categories.id = posts.category_id');
  $query = $this->db->get('posts');
  return $query->result_array();
}

$query = $this->db->get_where('posts',array('slug'=>$slug));
  return $query->row_array();

}
```

view

```
  <ul class="pagination">

                    <?php echo $links; ?>

                  </ul>
```

///////////////////**UPDATE**/////////////

So this is how my code looks now after updating as your said.

```
public function index($offset=0){

//Pagination
   $config['base_url'] = base_url().'posts/index/';
   $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('posts');
   $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
   $config['num_links'] = 10;
   $config['per_page']=3;

  $limit = $config['per_page'];
  $offset = ($offset) * ($config['per_page']);

 this->pagination->initialize($config);


  $data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_posts(FALSE,$limit,$offset);
```

in the view I have it set to

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

*So now the issue is, it shows 3 rows(results) and when I click next it shows nothing and that's it, so now I am only getting 3 results only on the first page and none on the next pages. What is wrong?*

Answer (score 0):

Index Function Not Working Segment Use Query String

Answer (score 0):

if $offset is `current_page_number` starting on 0, definition should be:

```
//number of rows to get
$limit = $config['per_page'];
//where start to get it
$offset = ($offset) * ($config['per_page']);
$data['posts'] = this->post_model->get_posts(FALSE,$limit,$offset);
```

If you define offset as current_page, starting on 1.

```
public function index($offset = 1){
......
//number of rows to get
$limit = $config['per_page'];
//where start to get it
$offset = ($offset - 1) * ($config['per_page']);
$data['posts'] = this->post_model->get_posts(FALSE,$limit,$offset);
```

Talking about "Index Function Not Working Segment Use Query String"...

If you have $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE you should GET it

```
public function index() {
$page = $this->input->get('page');
...
$offset = ($page - 1) * ($config['per_page']);
...
```

Comment: Where would I put this exactly ? I am a little confused as pagination is new to me. The current page number confused me. Please explain this further. Thank you.

Comment: I added a update to my original post above following what you said, now I am getting a error showing only results on the first page none after that. Sorry for bothering you. I just really want to understand how this pagination works. Thanks for the help.